# React.js: Is it possible to convert a react component to HTML DOM's?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a map-based app that uses Google Map API to create markers and its info window in React.js. The `infowindow.setContent()` only accepts either a `String` or `HTML`. It's impossible for me to pass in `String` as I have a `button` that links to a specific method in another react component (something like: `_this.props.addList(place)` ). Thus I must fill the argument as HTML DOM as the following lines of code:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
var title = document.createElement('h4');
title.innerHTML = place.name;

var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-block';
btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('I want to go here !!'));

div.appendChild(title).appendChild(btn);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

  infowindow.setContent( div );
  infowindow.open(map, this);
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  _this.props.addList(place);
});
```

The codes work for me but I don't wanna create elements one by one. I've also tried to pass the argument with a React component but it seems not working:

```js
createMarker: function() {
  
  /** Some other lines of code */

  var _this = this;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infowindow.setContent( _this._renderInfoWindow(place) );
    infowindow.open(map, _this);

  });

},

// my infowindow rendering method
_renderInfoWindow: function(place) {
  return(
    <div>
      <h4>{place.name}</h4>
      <p>{place.cost}</p>
      <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block" onClick={this.props.addList.bind(this, place)}>I want to go here !! </button>
    </div>
  )
},
```

so is there another way to at least convert a react component to HTML so that I don't have to write `document.createElement()` one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can render a ReactElement in a detached DOM Node via [`React.render`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.render). Thus, the following code should work for you.

```
createMarker: function() {

  /** Some other lines of code */

  _this = this;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render( _this._renderInfoWindow(place), div );
    infowindow.setContent( div );
    infowindow.open(map, this);

  });

},
```

Comment: That was part of Dewey's code snippet. Unless `_this` was defined higher in the function body, it will indeed bleed to the global scope.

Comment: You should use `ReactDOM.render` instead, not `React.render`.

Answer (score 17):

You could also use React's renderToString() method

```
_renderInfoWindow: function(place) {
  return React.renderToString(
    <div>
      <h4>{place.name}</h4>
      <p>{place.cost}</p>
      <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block" onClick={this.props.addList.bind(this, place)}>I want to go here !! </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This should work for a simple component as shown.
React.renderToString() will return only the html for the component.

Comment: I used `import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server' and `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup`

Comment: The button event handler does not work using this approach.

Comment: I recommend against using ReactDOMServer, it will require polyfills to run on browsers from Webpack v5+.

Answer (score 16):

For newer versions of React

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div>...</div>)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how it's supposed to be done in React 18:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const div = document.createElement('div');
const root = createRoot(div);
flushSync(() => {
  root.render(<MyIcon />);
});
console.log(div.innerHTML); // For example, "<svg>...</svg>"
```

The main part I was missing while trying to migrate to React 18 was the `flushSync` part. Before adding it my `innerHtml` always returned empty string.

According to this post: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString#removing-rendertostring-from-the-client-code

> The flushSync call is necessary so that the DOM is updated before
> reading its innerHTML property.

Also, `renderToString` and importing `react-dom/server` into the browser is still not recommended.

Comment: this gave me an error. ` Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 4):

This should render the HTML.

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div>...</div>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre's method is now deprecated and was never idiomatic. This is the new way, written idiomatically:

```
createMarker: function() {

  /** Some other lines of code */

  _this = this;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(div)
    root.render(<InfoWindow place={place} addList={...} />));
    infowindow.setContent(div);
    infowindow.open(map, this);

  });

},

// my infowindow rendering method
function InfoWindow ({ place, addList }) {
  return(
    <div>
      <h4>{place.name}</h4>
      <p>{place.cost}</p>
      <button className="btn btn-danger btn-block" onClick={() => addList(place)}>I want to go here !! </button>
    </div>
  )
},
```

Notice the mixing of JSX into the click handler and the extraction of InfoWindow into its own component: idiomatic React.

The next issue to fix is the creation of multiple roots on the same node. This can be fixed by keeping in to a single, shared one:

```
constructor() {
  this.infoWindowDiv = document.createElement('div');
  this.infoWindowReactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(this.infoWindowDiv)
}
```

and later...

```
this.infoWindowReactRoot.render(<InfoWindow place={place} addList={...} />));
```

Comment: Error: 'ReactDOM is undefined'

Comment: error 2:  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: @johnk You can find solutions to both of these by searching the errors

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a DOM element to hold the react component.
var span = document.createElement('span');
// Render the React component.
React.render(h.button(null, 'Buttonz!'), span);
// This will give the result as a string, which is useful if you've escaped
// React's context (e.g. inside DataTables).
// Obviously, the component will no longer be reactive but this is a
// good way to leverage simple stuff you've already written in React.
// In my case, I'm primarily leveraging React wrappers around Bootstrap components.
// The important thing is that componentDidMount gets called.
return span.outerHTML;
```