# React Element on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, highcharts

Is it possible to render a react component on highcharts' chart? HTML is possible using methods of [SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) but how to do it for react component?

Minimal Reproducer / Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/k07g9aj6/

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }]
})

class ReactButton extends React.Component {
        _onClick() {
            console.log("Clicked");
    }
    
    render() {
            return <button onClick={this._onClick}>ReactButton</button>;
    }
}

chart.renderer.button(<ReactButton />, 100, 200,).attr({
        zIndex: 3
}).add();
```

Note that button is only an example here, I want to know if I can render any complex react component on highcharts' chart. One way I considered was converting the react element to html and read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586411/react-js-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-react-component-to-html-doms) but it does not work for me as I expect it to.

I also considered rendering over the svg element but I am not sure if that is the best solution and also it may be hard to keep it responsive.

Can you please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only pure HTML is allowed to render through the renderer method. To use React components you have to convert them to HTML by using `renderToString` or `renderToStaticMarkup` methods, or use portals and render components into already exisitng chart elements.

**Useful thread:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/23

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-react-component-to-a-charts-element