# populate data in html with html string conversion

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I want to save my table data as pdf format in device but i have to pass html code which create a PDF file because i am using `react-native-html-pdf` library. i have wrote the code but my unable to populate my data in string format html. how can i implement it with html string converstion   so, please suggest solution of this problem.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

const data = {
  headers: ['Name', 'Country', 'City', 'Mobile', 'Salary', 'Date', 'PAN'],

  rows: [
    ['Maxwell', 'Australia', 'Sydney', '123', '$22', '02/02/89', 'yes'],
    ['Mark', 'Canada', 'Toronto', '056', '$8965', '12/06/02', 'no'],
    ['David', 'United Kingdom', 'London', '242', 'S23', '25/02/20', ''],
    ['Kohli', 'India', 'Delhi', '8956', '$32', '04/12/21', 'yes'],
    ['ABD', 'RSA', 'captown', '4515', '$32', '2/11/08', null],
  ],
};

export default class PdfTest extends Component {
  async createPDF() {
    let options = {
      html: `
      <html>
      <head>
      <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      
      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
      </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      
      <h2>HTML Table</h2>
      
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
          <td>Maria Anders</td>
          <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
          <td>Francisco Chang</td>
          <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ernst Handel</td>
          <td>Roland Mendel</td>
          <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Island Trading</td>
          <td>Helen Bennett</td>
          <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
          <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
          <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
          <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      
  `,
      fileName: 'table3',
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
    // console.log(file.filePath);
    Alert.alert(file.filePath);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.createPDF}>
          <Text>Create PDF</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use React.renderToString.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586411/react-js-is-it-possible-to-convert-a-react-component-to-html-doms

Comment: @iCoders Actually, i want to compile this html at this same component so, i have to populate data here.

Comment: html:this._renderInfoWindow() ,what about if we call like this..i am not 100% sure about it.just guessing based on your code

Comment: @iCoders acually, i am new is react, so can you please help me to implement it